# Find Nth highest number in a given nxn matrix

Tags: matrix

for given nxn matrix in which rows are sorted we need to find the given highest number . 
By using the feature "Each rows are sorted in a given matrix".  Plzz help me to write a optimized logic ..

ex  :
suppose we have a 3x3 matrix in which rows are sorted

```
  3   50  92
  59  84  90
  9   65  74

findhigestNum(4) --->  59
findhigestNum(5) ----> 65
```

Comment: which language do you need this in ?

Comment: I can't see that having the data in a matrix makes it easier to locate the nth highest number.  Sorting all the digits into descending order and picking the Nth can be done in O(n log(n) ) time complexity which seems like it would be hard to beat.

Comment: @DaveDurbin, each row is already sorted. That should help some sort of selection algorithm. But note that finding the kth number in an *unsorted* list of n elements is O(n) if you use the right sort of algorithm, and not O(n log n). Look up "selection algorithm".

Comment: Whilst each row is sorted, this tells you nothing about the relative contents of a row. Consider the 4x4 matrix  [1  2  6  10; 1 3  7  11; 1 4 8 12; 1  5  9  13], the rows containing the nth highest numbers are [4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 3 2 1] and you'd have to examine every digit to determine this. i.e. the fact that the rows are sorted won't get you a quicker answer. Good point re: finding kth number in an unsorted list though.